# Invalid cast exception, no redirection or alerts

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a SQL procedure which returns OutRes

```
protected void LoginButton_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  int Results = 0;

  using (SqlConnection sc1 = new SqlConnection())
  {
    sc1.ConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Drug;Integrated Security=True";
    SqlCommand sqlcom = new SqlCommand("user_login",sc1);
    {
        sqlcom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlcom.Parameters.Add("@UsernameSP", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = this.txtUserName.Text.Trim();
        sqlcom.Parameters.Add("@PasswordSP", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = this.txtPwd.Text.Trim();
        sqlcom.Parameters.Add("@OutRes", SqlDbType.VarChar, 4);
        sqlcom.Parameters["@OutRes"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        sqlcom.Connection = sc1;

        try
        {
            sc1.Open();
            sqlcom.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Results =(int)sqlcom.Parameters["@OutRes"].Value;
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('" + ex.Message + "')", true);
        }
        finally
        {
            sqlcom.Dispose();
            if (sc1 != null)
            {
                sc1.Close();
            }

        }
    } 
    if (Results == 0)
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('" + "result 0" + "')", true);
    else
     { 
     ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('" + "result 1" + "')", true);
     Response.Redirect("/DrugEntry.aspx");
     }
}
```

1. Invalid cast exception here:

   "Results =(int)sqlcom.Parameters["@OutRes"].Value;
   System.InvalidCastException was unhandled by user code
   Message=Specified cast is not valid"
2. The code does not display alerts or redirect either. What is happening?

---

This is not getting displayed. And my Results variable stored  0 or 1 depending on my query.

```
if (Results == 0)
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('" + "result 0" + "')", true);
else
{ ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('" + "result 1" + "')", true);
Response.Redirect("DrugEntry.aspx");
}
```

Both the alerts are not displayed. Any Idea why?

Comment: Whatever is coming out of `sqlcom.Parameters["@OutRes"].Value` can not be cast to an integer.

Comment: You don't get alert because the exception is not of type SqlException.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to change type of `@Outres Parameter` from Varchar to `Int`.

```
protected void LoginButton_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  int Results = 0;
  using (SqlConnection sc1 = new SqlConnection())
  {
      sc1.ConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Drug;Integrated Security=True";
      SqlCommand sqlcom = new SqlCommand("user_login",sc1);
      {
         sqlcom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
         sqlcom.Parameters.Add("@UsernameSP", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = this.txtUserName.Text.Trim();
         sqlcom.Parameters.Add("@PasswordSP", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = this.txtPwd.Text.Trim();
         sqlcom.Parameters.Add("@OutRes", SqlDbType.Int, 4);
         sqlcom.Parameters["@OutRes"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
         sqlcom.Connection = sc1;

         try
         {
           sc1.Open();
           sqlcom.ExecuteNonQuery();
           Results =(int)sqlcom.Parameters["@OutRes"].Value;

         }
         catch (SqlException ex)
         {
              ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('" + ex.Message + "')", true);

         }
         finally
         {
            sqlcom.Dispose();
            if (sc1 != null)
            {
               sc1.Close();
            }

        }
    } 
    if (Results == 0)
       ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('" + "result 0" + "')", true);
    else
    { 
       ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage",   "alert('" + "result 1" + "')", true);
       Response.Redirect("/DrugEntry.aspx");
    }
 }
```

Comment: You can't be sure it's actually an integer in the database. If he does that, he should be storing it as a number in the DB to begin with, not as a varchar.

Comment: Because it probably is numeric. Anyway the point is that if he's casting it to an integer later down the line in code, it should be using the `INTEGER` SQL type rather than varchar to begin with.

Comment: Although you do state what the problem is, it's much better to show just the change that you've made, rather than copy/paste the entire code and expect people to find the one line

Answer (score 2):

You are passing `Output` parameter as `Varchar` and trying to convert after `ExecuteNonQuery) as`Int`

```
 Results =(int)sqlcom.Parameters["@OutRes"].Value;
```

If you are casting it as `Int` then you must pass it as `Int` into `Parameter` and it should be as `Int` in your `StoredProcedure` as well.

change it and it will work for you.

Comment: a bit safer with not Int.TryParse()

Comment: PERFECT! THANKS!

Any idea why the alerts are not popping up?

Comment: Wrap your message inside `script` tag like this `"alertMessage", "<script>alert('" + ex.Message + "');</script>"` and instead of `SqlException` you should use `Exception` to catch any error..

Comment: @divinediu If you are thanking him then i think this should be accepted as Answer.

Comment: @Neon-X I had two queries. Everybody helped. I'd mark both as answers, I can't. :(

Answer (score 0):

1. Try using `Convert.ToInt32(sqlcom.Parameters["@OutRes"].Value);`
   instead of casting
2. You're catching SqlException, and the exception raised is InvalidCastException, that's why the catch block didn't catch it.